# Terminology for masking complexity in programming languages

Tags: terminology

...where underneath, the process for a particular function is the same as if the developer manually coded the function himself, but the language allows him to execute that function with a simple command.

By "complexity", I mean general-English complexity not computer science run-time complexity.

i.e.

Language 1: input "1 + 2 + 3" to add the numbers together to get output "6".

Language 2: input "B" to get output "6" but the program still achieves the result by adding the numbers "1", "2", "3".

This is the case for an interface in C# where the interface helps us code more conveniently but we don't need to know the implementation underneath in order to use it. Also the underlying motivation for the creation of jQuery or higher-level programming languages. What is this concept called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's been a week and I just found out it's called ABSTRACTION. Why does no one know this?! smh

Comment: As abstraction is not to mask something, it's to make something abstract ;). Your question was not clear what you are looking for.